# Iterating through select statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

First table is `service` table and the second table is `reservation` table.

My requirement is: first I need to select service_id,amount from service table and if the selected service_id is there in reservation table on the particular date then I need to select total_seats value as it is. If the selected service ids from service table is not there on the particular date in reservation table then I need to select the total_seats value as 60.

```
----------------------       
| service_id |amount |   
----------------------   
| 3000       | 500   |   
----------------------   
| 3001       | 300   |   
----------------------   
| 3002       | 800   |   
----------------------   

---------------------------------------   
| bus_service_id |  DOJ       |total_seats  
------------------------------------------  
|  3002          | 2013-10-11 |   23    
------------------------------------------  
|  3001         | 2013-10-6   |   26    
------------------------------------------  
|  3001         | 2013-10-12  |  50    
------------------------------------------
|  3000         | 2013-10-6   | 41  
------------------------------------------
```

Please help me how to do this? I need to pass one input parameter DOJ.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
SELECT IFNULL(total_seats, 60) total_seats
FROM service_table s
LEFT JOIN reservation_table r
ON s.service_id = r.bus_service_id AND DOJ = @DOJ
```

The `DOJ` test has to be in the `ON` clause so that the test doesn't filter out the null rows that result if there's no match.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when total_seats is null then 60 else total_seats end as total_seats
from service_table
left outer join reservation_table
    on service_table.service_id = reservation_table.bus_service_id
where DOJ = @DOJ
```

You need to use a left outer join, or else you'll eliminate the values in service_table for which there is no bus_service_id in reservation_table.  The CASE statement is kind of like a switch statement, so if there is no matched value from the reservation_table, we'll return 60.  You could also include the DOJ = @DOJ in the join condition, if you find that more clear.  Of course, I've also omitted the parameter declaration; it will vary based on whether it is an argument to a function or part of the script.

Comment: You need to put `DOJ = @DOJ` into the `ON` clause, otherwise the null rows will be eliminated. Also, I suggest using `COALESCE` or `IFNULL` instead of the verbose `CASE` statement.

Comment: Hi @prekolna thanks for your answer.I'm not getting the answer because  if the bus_service_id value on the particular date is not there then in that also I need to fetch total_seats value as 60.